# Ruby on Rails search_field_tag class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

sorry for asking a question again but since my other question got answered I got a new problem

How am I able to give search_field_tag a class such as form-control? I tried multiple ways including this one for example:

```
<%= search_field_tag :q, '', html_options: { class: 'form-control' } %>
```

But this doesn't work. The field_tag gets invisible when trying it with this.

Any chance to do this? I googled up the documentation for search_field_tag and it says `search_field_tag(name, value = nil, options = {})`.

Answer (score 1):

[search_field_tag](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/search_field_tag)

```
<%=search_field_tag :q, '', class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter query'%>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It throws no error but the box itself gets still invisible.

Comment: @flenning12 Inspect `search_field_tag` element, in browser console, and check if class is there on that field, it may be invisible, cause of some css issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= form_for "",url: cars_path, role: "search", method: :get  ,class: "navbar-form navbar-right" do %>
         <%= text_field_tag :search, @search_term,placeholder: "Search..."  %>
<% end %>
```

OR

```
 <%= search_field_tag :q, '', { :class => 'form-control' }) %>
```

Check out this example!